# Spring AMQP: RabbitMQ Delayed Message Exchange: `amqp_delay` not translated to `x-delay`

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a RabbitMQ exchange of type `x-delayed-message` using the delayed message exchange plugin.

I know when I return a `org.springframework.messaging.Message` with the header `AmqpHeaders.DELAY` set, the delay functionality works. I would assume that the framework is at some point translating `amqp_delay` (value of `AmqpHeaders.DELAY`) to `x-delay`.

But when I retury a `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message`, the message just get's sent with the header `amqp_delay` instead of the `x-delay` header that RabbitMQ expects.

Is this an oversight on the part of Spring AMQP?

Given the `AmqpHeaders` class is in the `spring-amqp` artifact and under the `org.springframework.amqp.support`, shouldn't the value of `AmqpHeaders.DELAY` be `x-delay` instead of `amqp_delay`.

If not, shouldn't the framework atleast translate the header keys?

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an conversion is done in the `SimpleAmqpHeaderMapper`:

```
.acceptIfNotNull(getHeaderIfAvailable(headers, AmqpHeaders.DELAY, Integer.class),
                amqpMessageProperties::setDelay)
```

which is used from the `MessagingMessageConverter`. And this one is used in the `RabbitMessagingTemplate`.

so, if you create a `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message` yourself, you really need to populate a `x-delay` header instead. The `AmqpHeaders` is used only in case of `org.springframework.messaging.Message`.